# OnSubmit Behavior for Lightning-Record-Edit-Form in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to determine if something is possible with Lightning Web Component's "[lightning-record-edit-form][1]".  I've set up a small LWC for creating Lead's in a Community in our org, and have utilized the record-edit-form to display some fields on Lead, collect the information, and submit it to create a new record.  Here's the abbreviated code:

HTML:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form
    object-api-name={leadObject}
    onsubmit={handleSubmitLead}
    onsuccess={handleSuccess}
    onerror={handleLoading}
>
    <!-- Messages -->
    <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
    <!-- Spinner -->
    <div>
        // Conditional to display spinner while loading
    </div>
    <!-- Fields -->
    <div>
        // Handful of Lead fields here
    </div>
    <br/>
    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
        <lightning-button class="slds-p-around_x-small" variant="brand" type="submit" label="Create Lead"></lightning-button>
        <lightning-button class="slds-p-around_x-small" variant="neutral" name="cancelLead" label="Cancel" onclick={handleNotify}></lightning-button>
    </div>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

JS:

```
handleSubmitLead(event) {
        this.editing = !this.editing;
        this.loaded = !this.loaded;

        event.preventDefault();
        const fields = event.detail.fields;

        fields[LEAD_RTID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = [Custom Lead RTID];

        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
    }
```

**My question is: would it be possible to have a second lightning-button in my form, also using the type="submit" tag, and then be able to determine in the JavaScript which of the two were clicked?**  I'm looking to have a "Create" button and then a "Create & Submit" button which would set an additional custom field to trigger a Process Builder further downstream.

From what I've tested, the usual event.target call to try and find details about the button clicked doesn't work here, possibly due to Shadow DOM restrictions?  I considered using a separate button with an explicit onClick call to another method, but then I think I'd lose visibility to the fields that are populated in the form?

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but I doubt you can. This is what I read on [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event): *Note that the submit event fires on the `<form>` element itself, and not on any `<button>` or `<input type="submit">` inside it. (Forms are submitted, not buttons.)*